# Without auto increment I have to add row with continue Id no

Tags: oracle

I need to add a new row in existing table using Oracle plsql.which doesn't have unique identity column. For example table contain id_no,name of 40 rows.i need to add 40 more rows in same table. I want to add next continues number of max(id_no). For name I am going to insert it manually.without using auto increment.

Comment: How you will insert the rows? Using Insert statement or selecting from another table?

Comment: can you create a sequence?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. The first bug is existing table which `doesn't have unique identity`. This means either you do not have a unique value or at least a uniquely auto assigned id. Both are a extremely poor design. First step: Fix not having a uniquely auto assigned id. Next step: Add your new rows letting id be auto assigned. DO NOT use max+1 to assign id. In a multi-user environment this is a *virtual guarantee* of getting a duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

Try an insert statement with subquery select max(id_no)+1 from table.